# Should homework tag be deprecated/burninated?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate

The [homework tag was deprecated from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) in 2012 - should GIS Stack Exchange do the same?

Rather than repeat too much of the [discussion of what led Stack Overflow to burninate this tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) on over 20,000 questions (we had 19 when this one was originally asked), I propose a show of hands (votes) to monitor what the community feeling is here.

[How to treat a "please do my homework for me" question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423) prompted this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vote for this Answer if you think the [homework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag should be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag).

Answer (score 4):

Vote for this Answer if you think the [homework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag should be **retained**.