# whether to use self-study tag

Tags: discussion, tags

There are plenty of questions in GIS SE that are  routine question from a textbook, course, or test used for a class or self-study.

I would recommend to use self-study tag (which I created) more often here to categorize such questions; I also have seen it in other communities.

Example questions that are fit with this tag:

- [Python Geospatial development book error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109005/python-geospatial-development-book-error)
- [SQL Server data modelling + spatial data = what book?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48042/sql-server-data-modelling-spatial-data-what-book)

Would this tag be appropriate for this community? So to encourage editors and moderators use it more often?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your newly coined [self-study](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) tag should be a synonym of [homework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).

However, the [homework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag appears to be on the way to burnination in [Should the homework tag be deprecated/burninated?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3427/115)

The Q&A titled [How to treat a "please do my homework for me" question?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-treat-a-please-do-my-homework-for-me-question) seems to define our de facto policy on homework questions and I think the same should apply to self-study.

Summing up, I do not think that either the [self-study](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study) or [homework](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tags should be used, and any question, irrespective of whether they are for homework or self-study, should be assessed for GIS SE suitability by the same criteria as every other question asked here.